# Sencha Touch 2 Google maps events (click,double click...) not fired in Android device (APK)

Tags: extjs

I tried to handle Google maps event in a Sencha Touch app. When I tested the application in Chrome, Google maps events (click, double click, mousedown...) work fine. However, when I generated the Android application version, none of those events are working anymore on the Android version.  How can I correct this bug such that I can handle at least the click and double click events on the Android APK version?

The following are functions that I used to handle Google maps events:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    Ext.Msg.alert("click", "lat" + event.latLng.lat());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {
    Ext.Msg.alert("dblclick", "lat" + event.latLng.lat());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event) {
    Ext.Msg.alert("mousedown", "mousedown");
});
```